# Apple Mail on iOS 11.4.1 completely broken

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I'm trying to connect to my Gmail from Mail but it says *cannot get mail* imap.gmail.com

I cannot access any settings to change this from the app or the Settings app.

Comment: Can you edit the question to describe the steps you are taking to add the gmail account? It's likely that the problem is due to some configuration issue rather than the app itself.

Comment: The account was there since 4 years ago on this iphone account

Comment: Is it a standard Gmail account or a custom domain used with Google G-Suite?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have a typo in the server name.

Try changing it to **imap**.gmail.com. There's a guide to gmail's imap server settings [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en).

Comment: there is no way to edit my settings

Comment: Post a a screenshot of Settings -> Accounts & Passwords on your original question and I'll take a look, thanks!